# Force this expression to be simplified

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to simplify the following expression

$$\frac{\text{C3B} \times \text{R2B} \times s \times \sqrt{\frac{\text{R5B} \times(\text{R1B}+\text{R2B})}{\text{R1B} \times \text{R2B}}}}{\sqrt{\text{C3B} \times \text{C4B}} \times\sqrt{\text{R1B}+\text{R2B}} \times \sqrt{\text{C3B} \times \text{C4B} \times \text{R1B} \times \text{R2B} \times\text{R5B}}}$$

This is supposed to simply simplify to

$$\frac{1}{\text{R1B} \times \text{C4B}} s$$

How can I do it? I think Mathematica is assuming that the variables can be complex or real and negative, but they are real and positive. How can I force Mathematica to do this simplification? Thank you!

EDIT:

Workable code example

```
i=2;
components = {"R1", "R2", "C3", "C4", "R5"};
components = StringInsert[components, ToString[ToUpperCase[FromLetterNumber[i]]], -1];
components = ToExpression[components];
Ksymbolic = components[[5]]/components[[1]]*(1 + components[[4]]/components[[3]])^-1;
wpsymbolic = Sqrt[components[[1]] + components[[2]]]/ Sqrt[components[[1]]*components[[2]]*components[[3]]*components[[4]]*components[[5]]];
Qpsymbolic = Sqrt[components[[3]]*components[[4]]]/(components[[3]] + components[[4]])*Sqrt[components[[5]]/components[[1]] + components[[5]]/components[[2]]];
numTSectionSymbolic = Assuming[components > 0, Simplify[Ksymbolic*wpsymbolic/Qpsymbolic*s]];
```

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code.

Comment: You need assumptions to simplify further: `Simplify[ ...,{R1B>0,R2B>0}]`

Comment: @cvgmt I have posted a workable example code, thank you

Comment: @UlrichNeumann yes I am trying to do something like that, but failing. I have posted a workable example.

Comment: `Thread[components > 0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica doesn't understand `components>0`!

Change the last line of your code to

```
Simplify[Ksymbolic*wpsymbolic/Qpsymbolic*s, Map[# > 0 &, components]]
(*s/(C4B R1B)*)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I still struggle from lack of practice on using that "Map" command, but I have seen as a solution to many problems I have faced in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
PowerExpand[Simplify[Ksymbolic*wpsymbolic/Qpsymbolic*s]]
```